# Typescript: Extract from discriminated union with multiple identical types

Tags: typescript

I have a type like below:

```js
type Entity =
  | {
      type: 'user' | 'person';
      id: string;
    }
  | {
      type: 'animal';
      id: number;
    };
```

Now I want to extract the types from it:

`type Animal = Extract<Entity, {type: 'animal'}>` - works perfectly (returns `{ type: 'animal'; id: number; }`);

`type User = Extract<Entity, {type: 'user'}>` - returns `never`.

How can I make it return `{ type: 'user'; id: string; }`
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provided documenation for `Extract<T, U>` says:

> Extract from T those types that are assignable to U

And `{ type: 'user' | 'person', id: string }` is not assignable to `{ type: 'user' }`

```
declare const entity: Entity
const user: { type: 'user' } = entity
/*
Type 'Entity' is not assignable to type '{ type: "user"; }'.
  Type '{ type: "user" | "person"; id: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: "user"; }'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"user" | "person"' is not assignable to type '"user"'.
        Type '"person"' is not assignable to type '"user"'.(2322)
*/
```

Which means you cannot use `Extract` to do this.

---

But what you can do is use an intersection (`&`), which will trim away any union members that cannot be matched by that discriminant.

```
type User = Entity & { type: 'user' }

const user: User = { type: 'user', id: 'abc' }
user.id // type: string
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqKBeAUFKAfKBvTLI0SALigHIBXAZwgCcKdLJ6aB7OCgbkKKkQATcjWD1EcAOa9+AX0K4C-LCQjkKAQziIAthoA2PPkSHk4VHQCMGMorN7pVUAKp16aWAmQgoAMnxQquq0DEzy6ADGnKJQIfTkrgweeIHgapRxFAA0AsKUGpYRYehxAHRCUAD0lalkUKLiUkA)

Answer (score 4):

Extracting the first element of the union using `Extract` does not work as `'user' | 'person'` is not assignable to `'user'`. We need to write our own `CustomExtract` which matches for `Partial<T>`.

```
type CustomExtract<T, U> = 
  T extends T 
    ? U extends Partial<T> 
      ? T 
      : never
    : never

type Animal = CustomExtract<Entity, { type: 'animal' }>
// type Animal = {
//     type: 'animal';
//     id: number;
// }

type User = CustomExtract<Entity, { type: 'user' }>
// type User = {
//     type: 'user' | 'person';
//     id: string;
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqKBeAUFKAfKBvTLI0SALigHIBXAZwgCcKdLJ6aB7OCgbkKKkQATcjWD1EcAOa9+AX0K4C-LCQjkKAQziIAthoA2PPkSHk4VHQCMGMorN7pVUAMK1g7HTAAeYjQGNgAB4AFQAaKABVAD40KEJgqAgfCDhBGigE4wB+SMTk1PSABQ16JAMQmOMsHMzlKDMIADcGYwbm+nRHcGgAQW09fVjXUQ9vXwDA+CRQcLwoVXUtXQMmWSj0AHoN+e6oPuXB1HxN7f4FyiWBoy3lUyhzKxsTqHkuyEi6eiG3UZ96fyCU2QIFmOzIlFoDFW6xuTgin1iBBuZ266khjGYFFYHC4vGRJmEUFE4ikeO2siAA)